# How to make PreferenceActivity update faster?

Tags: java, android, preferenceactivity

I have set PreferenceActivity to set IP address. After it is saved , it shows me that it is set , but when to use it , shows me " ". It uses the IP I set only after i restart my app.

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could show some code to make your question clearer

Comment: Could you use SharedPreferences?

Comment: After i save my preferences i cant use them , i have to restart my app

Comment: in other class i have the method that calls SP

  private final SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    private SharedPreferences settings;

 public String getIp() {
        return settings.getString(Constants.KEY_IP, "");
    }

Comment: Chrome Penguin Studios the idea is that i cant use them at 1st session of app , only after i restart my app